# Print the number of characters which are identical and occur in the same position in both strings

Tags: string, for-loop, go

For example if "abacdead" and "adcbadedga" are the two strings then we need to print the same position and different position.

```
    same pos count: 2
    diff pos count: 5
```

If we are using loop means, a (first letter) will be checking all the characters (string 2), So the loop will be run by more than 140 times, Here How can we achieve the O (n). If we have any data structure, Please suggest me to solve this issue.

**Sample code**

```
   func Test(a, b string) {
    r := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(b); j++ {
            if string(a[i]) == string(b[j]) {
                r = append(r, map[string]interface{}{
                    "position": i,
                    "char":     string(a[i]),
                })
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about this: `a = "xbc", b="xxx"`. The char `'x'` has a matching position at `0`, but also 2 non-matching at `2` and `3`. What should be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need the count of characters in the same position, and the total count of each character in each string.  Then sum the minimum count of each character, and subtract the count in the same position.

https://play.golang.org/p/pknsVfZ1ZbM

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math"
)

func main() {
  a := []rune("abacdead")
  b := []rune("adcbadedga")
  same := 0
  chars := make(map[rune][]int)
  for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
      if i < len(b) && a[i] == b[i] {
          same++
      }
      if _, ok := chars[a[i]]; !ok {
          chars[a[i]] = []int{0, 0}
      }
      chars[a[i]][0]++
  }
  for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
      if _, ok := chars[b[i]]; !ok {
          chars[b[i]] = []int{0, 0}
      }
      chars[b[i]][1]++
  }

  different := -same
  for char, vals := range chars {
      fmt.Println(string(char), vals[0], vals[1])
      different += int(math.Min(float64(vals[0]), float64(vals[1])))
  }
  fmt.Println("Same: ", same, "Different: ", different)
}
```

Caveat being that the totals don't agree with what you said:

```
"abacdead"
"adcbadedga"
```

same position we have the first `a` and the last `d`, if we remove those:

```
"bacdea"
"dcbadega"
```

and then sort

```
"aabcde"
"aabcddeg"
```

we then remove unmatched letters

```
"aabcde"
"aabcde"
```

we should have *six* identical characters in different positions.